Using scale pos weight and non 0.5 cut off score for a look-alike model
I'm working on a classification problem where I'm trying to identify look-alikes of Class 1 in Class 0. Class 1 and Class 0 are established based on type of product customers use. Basically, Class 1 customers own product A and exhibit certain behaviors. class 0 customers own product B but, some of these customers exhibit behavior similar to that of Class 1 customers owning product A.
My model aims to identify Class 0 customers exhibiting Class 1 behavior such that Class 0 customers can be targeted to migrate to product A. Let's call such customers look-alikes.
Basically, I only have confirmed Class 1 customers. Class 0 is a mixed set of customers in a way. I'm building a classifier to identify the look-alikes in Class 0. Basically, the false positives identified by the model.
The real world ratio of class 1 and class 0 is about 1:10. My sample has the ratio 1:4. I'm using a xgboost classifier with scale pos weight ~4.
I'm trying to be conservative and use a higher cut-off score of 0.7 to identify the look-alikes. i.e, any class 0 customer who gets a score of 0.7 or higher are considered as look-alikes. I'm using recall as model performance metric, with 0.7 cutoff I get a recall of 0.7 and look-alike or False Positive Rate as 0.05 (5%). Which looks reasonable given the business use case.
My question is, does it makes sense to use both scale pos weight and a higher cut off score in cases like these? Does my modeling approach sound problematic?
